# NullPointerException when I try to insert data into database in Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

I'm trying to insert data into database in thread, but I have a error:

```
01-23 17:17:58.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-23 17:17:58.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-23 17:17:58.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-23 17:17:58.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-23 17:17:58.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-23 17:17:58.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-23 17:17:58.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-23 17:17:58.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-23 17:17:58.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 17:17:58.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball.MyTask.insertData(MyTask.java:59)
01-23 17:17:58.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball.MyTask.doInBackground(MyTask.java:22)
01-23 17:17:58.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball.MyTask.doInBackground(MyTask.java:1)
01-23 17:17:58.127: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
```

I want to adding acceleration position from class MainActivity ( from variables) at every 1 second, so I insert this data into ContentValues, next, from contentvalues to database.

```
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        MainActivity main = new MainActivity();


        private int abc;
        float xPositionGlobal, yPositionGlobal;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                insertData();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d("appname","błąd w doInBackground");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
            float xPosition = event.values[0];
            float yPosition = event.values[1];

            xPositionGlobal = xPosition;
            yPositionGlobal = yPosition;


        }


    public void insertData() throws InterruptedException{

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            Date date = new Date();


        while(true){
            long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            abc++;

            values.put(Database.ID, 1+abc);
            values.put(Database.LEFT_POSITION, xPositionGlobal);
            values.put(Database.RIGHT_POSITION, yPositionGlobal);
        //  values.put(Database.GPS, main.GPSposition);
            values.put(Database.GPS, "3");
            values.put(Database.TIME, date.toString());


            if(main.myDBAdapter.db != null){

                main.myDBAdapter.db.insert("baza", null, values);
                Thread.sleep(1000 - millis % 1000);

            }else{
                Log.d(Database.DB_NAME,"db is null");
            }

        }

        }
```

OnClick method from MainActivity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bStart:


        myDBAdapter = new Database(this).open();

            new MyTask().execute();

        case R.id.bStop:

            myDBAdapter.close();
            break;

        }

    }


}
```

When i use Database myDBAdapter = new Database(); , logcat say db is null

Comment: I'm trying to find information how I can get full stack trace, but I don't have any idea, sorry, I'm newbie :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyTask creates a new instance of "MainActivity" - where "myDBAdapter" is not initialized. You need to re-initialize it or move it.

You should probably move it because you probably don't want a reference to an activity instantiating on a background thread.

Comment: move it where? You mean I should create new instance of Database in MyTask class and use it without instance of MainActivity?

Comment: that sounds acceptable. AsyncTask is designed to offload "data intensive tasks" like database access from the UI thread. Keeping your adapter in the Activity puts it on the UI thread. You should not need it to execute in your Activity.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's nothing changed. When I deleted reference of MainActivity, and use Database myDBAdapter = new Database(null); logcat show: db is null. Maybe i should use different constructor?